# Create new XML file and write data to it?

Tags: php, xml, file

I need to create a new XML file and write that to my server. So, I am looking for the best way to create a new XML file, write some base nodes to it, save it. Then open it again and write more data.

I have been using `file_put_contents()` to save the file. But, to create a new one and write some base nodes I am not sure of the best method.

Ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/domdocument) is a great choice.  It's a module specifically designed for creating and manipulating XML documents.  You can create a document from scratch, or open existing documents (or strings) and navigate and modify their structures.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_album = $xml->createElement("Album");
$xml_track = $xml->createElement("Track");
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );

$xml->save("/tmp/test.xml");
```

To re-open and write:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('/tmp/test.xml');
$nodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Album') ;
if ($nodes->length > 0) {
   //insert some stuff using appendChild()
}

//re-save
$xml->save("/tmp/test.xml");
```

Comment: How do I keep the XML structure in my document, rather than everything being written on one line?

Comment: Set the "formatOutput" property on the DOMDocument object:  `$xml->formatOutput = true`.   http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput

Comment: its a bit late but if someone wants to read a tutorial can find here.        https://programmerblog.net/how-to-generate-xml-files-using-php/

Answer (score 13):

PHP has several libraries for [XML Manipulation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

The [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (DOM) approach (which is a W3C standard and should be familiar if you've used it in other environments such as a Web Browser or Java, etc). Allows you to create documents as follows

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument( );
    $ele = $doc->createElement( 'Root' );
    $ele->nodeValue = 'Hello XML World';
    $doc->appendChild( $ele );
    $doc->save('MyXmlFile.xml');
?>
```

Even if you haven't come across the DOM before, it's worth investing some time in it as the model is used in many languages/environments.

Answer (score 2):

With [**FluidXML**](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml) you can generate and store an XML document very easily.

```
$doc = fluidxml();

$doc->add('Album', true)
        ->add('Track', 'Track Title');

$doc->save('album.xml');
```

Loading a document from a file is equally simple.

```
$doc = fluidify('album.xml');

$doc->query('//Track')
        ->attr('id', 123);
```

https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml